# ASP .NET CORE WEB API & Angular Displaying an image in Angular from the WWWROOT on the server

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

The part of my server works as it should, I manage to upload photos into the WWWROOT
But I try to make a call to these images in the client but it does not show me the image.

[image]
[image]

In the Angular UI I did the INPUT TEXT but I want to convert it to img with src but when I do that it doesn't show me the image
[image]

Controller:

```
 formProfile:FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  isReadonly:boolean = true;
  user!:User;
  
  constructor(private userService:UserService,private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
    private alert:AlertService,private router:Router,public validationService:ValidationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.userService.getUser();
    
    this.formProfile = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName:[''],
      userName:[''],
      password:[''],
      email:[''],
      photoUrl:['']
    }) 
  }

  updateUser(){
    this.userService.updateUser(this.user.id,this.user)
    .subscribe(()=>{
      this.alert.success("Editing was done successfully");
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.user));
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    },(e) => {
      this.validationService.registerValidation(e); // change it
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="bg-info text-dark card">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3 class="title">My Profile</h3>
                </div>    
                <form [formGroup]="formProfile" (ngSubmit)="updateUser()">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="FullName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="fullName"
                           class="form-control" id="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" [readonly]="isReadonly"
                           [(ngModel)]="user.fullName">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" formControlName="email"
                         class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" [readonly]="isReadonly"
                          [(ngModel)]="user.email">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="UserName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="userName"
                         class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="User Name" [readonly]="isReadonly"
                          [(ngModel)]="user.userName">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="password"
                         class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" [readonly]="isReadonly"
                          [(ngModel)]="user.password">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Photo:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="photoUrl"
                         class="form-control" id="photo" placeholder="Photo" [readonly]="isReadonly"
                         [(ngModel)]="user.photoUrl">
                         <img  [src]="user.photoUrl">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <a (click)="toggleProfile()" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Change your Profile</a>
                    <div *ngIf="!isReadonly">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `ngModel` if you already have a reactive form...?

Comment: @Andres2142 So was it recommended to use this variable? **formProfile**

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing has some problems, you are using `ngModel` having reactive forms approach already set up. I always recommend using reactive forms, is more customizable and you have control over your form in your code.

Try refactoring your code by removing all `ngModel` bindings, after that,  populate your form, I see you already have `formControlName` on each of the controls, do it like this:

```js
setForm(): void {
  this.formProfile.setValue({
     fullname: this.user.name,
     username: this.user.username,
     password: this.user.password,
     theImage: this.user.src
     // ... etc
  })
}
```

Or you could also update individually each form control using `patchValue` like so:

```js
this.formProfile.get('fullname').pathValue(this.user.name);
// ...
```

Also, the image `src` you are getting back is missing in your frontend app, the backend is just giving you the name of the image, not the image itself, you should have that image in your `assets` folder, or the backend should provide the `url` of the image where is hosted.

If you wanna know more about `reactive forms` in Angular, I recommend reading the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: And in HTML instead of NGMODEL what should I do?

Comment: nothing... you manage EACH of the form controls in code like I'm showing in my answer, each control in your HTML should have `formControlName` in order reference it correctly.

Comment: But if I remove the NgModel from the HTML it does not show me my data

Comment: Read the official documentation on how reactive forms work please, when removing ngModel, how are you filling up your form? are you doing it as I posted?

Comment: I don't understand how I display the data without NgModel and I did as you wrote